# Como bloquear iframes em input

Tags: php

Olá, tenho um website com sistema de postagem e o problema é o seguinte: o usuário pode colocar um iframe do youtube por exemplo em qualquer resolução :

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/CKjPutIlBCA" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

quero colocar um limite de width e height, o problema é que o usuário manda o código e o sistema interpreta do jeito que ele escreve, queria que o sistema detecte o iframe e não deixe o user postar, ou senão libere o iframe e redimensione automaticamente, me ajudem não sei como faço isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No momento que receber o valor do input inserido pelo usuário, apenas sanitize o valor.

Exemplo:

```
$str = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>';
preg_match_all('#\bhttps?://[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/))#', $str, $match);
print_r($match);
```

Essa rotina extrai somente o que possui formato de URL.

Com isso, não precisa se preocupar se o usuário entrou com `iframe`, `frame`, `a href` ou qualquer outra coisa.

Se o resultado `preg_match_all()` não retornar nada na variável `$match`, possivelmente o usuário não inseriu nenhuma URL válida dentro da regra da expressão regular aplicada nessa rotina. Para esse caso, obviamente, retorne uma mensagem de erro ao usuário.

Há outras diferentes formas de extrair a URL com uso de outras funções e técnicas. Aplique o que for conveniente para o seu caso.

Comment: Obrigado, também consegui resolver com o FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS

Comment: Mas FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS apenas converte códigos html em htmlentities. Isso é totalmente diferente de extrair a URL.